# How to line up labels and read-only fields in a Bootstrap 2 form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

In bootstrap 2, what's *the recommended way* of lining up labels and read-only text fields *in a form*. The following code sample creates misaligned fields:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sample</legend>    
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Readonly Field</label>
            <div class="controls">
                Lorem Ipsum and then some
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Note that I can fix this up myself with custom CSS.  That's not the issue.  It just seems silly that this is not build-in so I feel like I must be overlooking something.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use the uneditable input

```
<span class="input-xlarge uneditable-input">Lorem Ipsum and then some</span>
```

EDIT:

As of bootstrap 3.0 a class has been added to handle this

> When you need to place regular, static text next to a form label
>   within a horizontal form, use the `.form-control-static` class on a `<p>`

```
<div class="controls">
  <p class="form-control-static">Lorem Ipsum and then some</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just realised my question was wrong which you answered perfectly, so I'll mark it as the right answer.  However any idea what to do if I just want text on the right side?

Comment: Right side of the label.  There are some cases where having a read-only text box doesn't fit.  Like my original example.

Comment: Sure, but what if I don't want an input-like looking field but rather just the pure text aligned with the label??

Comment: Go back to plain old CSS? Unfortunately Bootstrap doesn't solve everything. IMO Twitter itself is not king of forms, they use few of them really.

Comment: **check** [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs2.asp) and [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/53350/65932) post, hope helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hack. You can use <label> with class "checkbox"

In your case:

```
<div class="controls">
 <label class="checkbox">
     Lorem Ipsum and then some
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: "checkbox" gets the vertical alignment correct (we're looking for something with padding-top:5px, yes?) but isn't working on my page because it's adding an unwanted 20px padding-left too.   Think I'll probably go with a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

As of bootstrap 4.0 the `.form-control-static` class has been replaced by the `.form-control-plaintext` class.