# Line up labels and read only text in Twitter Bootstrap 2.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a mixture of editable and read-only fields which I want to style using Bootstrap. The editable fields are aligned correctly, but the read-only fields are not, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: readonly field]

The HTML I'm using is:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    John Smith
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" size="16" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="help-inline">dd/mm/yyyy</span>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I don't want to show a read-only input for the fields which can't be edited, as users get confused/frustrated when they can't click in the box, and these are fields which can never be edited so it doesn't really make sense to show them as disabled/read-only. I just want the text to be displayed and aligned correctly with the label. Is there a way I can do this, either by using something in Bootstrap or overriding the default styles?

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887430/how-to-line-up-labels-and-read-only-fields-in-a-bootstrap-form), which wasn't answered (at least not an answer to the original question), and as Bootstrap has had multiple releases in the past 7 months I thought it would be worth asking again in case anything had changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to line up labels and read-only fields in a Bootstrap form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887430/how-to-line-up-labels-and-read-only-fields-in-a-bootstrap-form)

Comment: I do mention that question explicitly in my question: "My question is similar to this one, which wasn't answered", so the two questions are already linked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create your own style and apply it as below -

```
.controls.readonly
{
  padding-top: 5px;
}

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Name</label>
  <div class="controls readonly">
    John Smith
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap doesn't cover every eventuality and you will need to make your own styles.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate that Bootstrap doesn't cover everything but it does seem a bit odd that it supports practically everything for forms except this one particular case.

I had to add more styles than just the padding-top (line-height and font-size) but it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 114):

As of bootstrap 3.0 a class has been added to handle this

> When you need to place regular, static text next to a form label
>   within a horizontal form, use the `.form-control-static` class on a `<p>`

```
<div class="controls">
  <p class="form-control-static">Lorem Ipsum and then some</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know. I haven't switched to 3.0 yet but I will probably use it for future projects.

Comment: I use `@Html.DisplayFor` and found I could put `form-control-static` in the surrounding div instead a `<p>` element.

Comment: @pwaring please consider selecting this as the chosen answer

Comment: @BenWest My question was originally about Bootstrap 2.0, so the accepted answer is the correct one (also I haven't tested this answer so I have no idea whether it works).

Comment: Show full examples please

Comment: @EduardoinNorway full examples of what?

Comment: @chrisvdp I guess Eduardo is looking for a full example of a label next to static text. I was assuming your answer would contain the same, although it's not too challenging to figure it out :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bootstrap 3, definitely use the `form-control-static` class. If that's not an option, you could use the `control-label` class and have another class that removes the bold font weight.

in your html:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Name</label>
  <label class="control-label static-text">
    John Smith
  </label>
</div>
```

in your css:

```
.static-text {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Just make sure you list the `static-text` class *after* `control-label` on the `class` attribute in your html. That is so that it will override the `font-weight` established by `control-label`.

In your case you might also want to adjust the font size.

Of course, if bootstrap ever changes the CSS properties on the `control-label` class, you might have to go back and adjust your `static-text` class.

Answer (score 1):

Like @pwaring said, for me more styling was needed as well:

```
.controls.readonly{
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding-top: 5px;
}

<div class="controls readonly">
    Lorem Ipsum and then some
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Simon's post, I added `display: inline-block;` to the CSS.

This is to match the display of the label and the text.

Answer (score 0):

This is using chris vdp's answer and providing full HTML for people that did not find chris's answer blindingly obvious (like me and Eduardo in Norway).

I am potentially showing more code than needed, but I found that the above solutions were not at the 'copy-paste level' which I need most of the time.  :-)  I wanted to provide you with something I know works and can by pasted into your code in a blindingly obvious fashion.  Just plunk this  structure anywhere in the  of your HTML.

Note: This works with and requires Bootstrap 3.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="personName" class="control-label col-sm-2">Name</label>
        <div class="controls col-sm-10">
            <p id="personName" class="form-control-static">John Smith</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="col-sm-3" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" size="16" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="help-inline col-sm-3">dd/mm/yyyy</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the `controls` class:

```
<style>
.controls.aligncorrect{
  padding-top: 5px;
}
</style>
```

and then using it like this:

```
<div class="controls aligncorrect" style="padding-top:5px;">
    John Smith
  </div>
```

Comment: Why would you define a CSS style and then add the same 5px padding inline?